# Generate standalone Jekyll page with variables

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to generate an *additional* Jekyll page called `posts.html`.

I'm looking to use the Jekyll variables such as `site.posts` to iterate through the posts I've written for my site, and create a standalone page (`posts.html`) using these variables.

Here's my current version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <main>
        {% for post in site.posts %}

            {{post.title}};{{post.date}},
        
        {%endfor%}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I include this at the root of my site, the command `bundle exec jekyll build` will build `posts.html` to my `_site` directory, but does not compile the variables into readable text. It outputs it in plaintext.

I've attempted to hook into the existing build cycle by moving the `posts.html` file to the `_includes` directory, and referencing it at the bottom of `blog.html`.

This *does* generate the HTML, but as part of the `index.html` like so:

```
... Additional markup here
</main>
    <section id="category-modal-bg"></section>
<section id="category-modal">
  <h1 id="category-modal-title"></h1>
  <section id="category-modal-content"></section>
</section>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <main>
        
            MyPostName;MyPostDate,
        
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

This makes sense as the `layouts/posts.html` file is an `include`, so building the markup where the include exists is working as expected.

I'm trying to compile the `posts.html` file as a standalone, navigatable file that will sit alongside my `_site/index.html`. If I need to copy this file across as part of my CI/CD pipeline thats fine too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty front matter before `posts.html` to let Jekyll process your file. (and move back `posts.html`)

```html
---
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <main>
        {% for post in site.posts %}

            {{post.title}};{{post.date}},
        
        {% endfor %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Any files **with front matter** are subject to processing. For each of these files, Jekyll makes a variety of data available via Liquid. ([Variables | Jekyll Doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/))

> You must **include front matter** on the page for Jekyll to process any Liquid tags on it. ([Front Matter | Jekyll Doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/03-front-matter/#use-front-matter))

---

However in most cases, this is better.

```html
---
layout: default
---
{% for post in site.posts %}

    {{post.title}};{{post.date}},

{% endfor %}
```

By using a [*layout*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/), you don't have to write `<head>` or `<footer>` again and again and again. *Layouts* also makes it easier to change `<head>`, etc. (let's say, you want to add Google Analytics someday.)

---

Besides, I think this may help you, though irrelevant to the question's title.

```html
---
layout: default
---
<ol>
    {% for p in site.posts %}
        <li><a href="{{ p.url | relative_url }}">{{ p.title }}</a> — {{ p.date }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Comprehensive version: [Pagination | Jekyll doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/)

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Sadly it doesn't (predictably) include scheduled posts in the `site.posts` tag, but this works perfectly for my question.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about scheduled posts… (This is my first _accepted answer_, thanks! :-)